# struts 2 devmode pages getting slow even for development environment

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have enable dev mode for struts 2 by placing below constants in the struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<!-- as per documentation below constant can spped up slow rendering -->
<constant name="struts.i18n.reload" value="false"/> 
<constant name="struts.configuration.xml.reload" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.freemarker.templatesCache" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.freemarker.templatesCache.updateDelay" value="120"/>
<constant name="struts.freemarker.mru.max.strong.size" value="120"/>
```

My page loads are terribly slow and lot of mime-type outputs can be seen on console.

Eg:-

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xwd</extension>
    <mime-type>image/x-xwindowdump</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
```

Please help to speed up the page rendering.

Comment: How could you know if it slow or fast, if you didn't measure the performance.

Comment: without devmode my application is responding reasonably good and it is in  production as well.I am updating latest jar of struts and want to debug application for framework errors .

Comment: With dev mode a page takes more than minute to load where as it is loding in matter of seconds when devmode is false.

Comment: Hm... looks ok, as per docs - so it must be something else - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/devMode#devMode-Pagerenderingisslow

Comment: Can you prepare a small demo app and post it somewhere?

Comment: The demo apps provided by apache with struts 2.3.16 is showing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I got the solution for the above issue :-

The huge console outputs are written by feemarker and OGNL.Most of the time is spent in writing console .
To reduce the console output hence reducing processing time we can set log level to "error" for below struts 2 components :-

```
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2=ERROR
log4j.logger.freemarker.cache=ERROR
log4j.logger.freemarker.beans=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2=ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record want to mention that per Struts documentation:

> Setting `devMode` to true will disable cache and `updateDelay` immediately.

So, the optimization configuration parameters that you have setup above will not be considered.